# Aloha Editor: is there a way to prevent it from breaking up a text node with <br> or <p> on enter or paste?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mathjax, aloha-editor

The aloha editor inserts either a `<br>` tag or a `<p>` tag when you press enter, or you paste something that has newlines in it. Now this was fine, until I wanted to use the `{aligned}` environment in MathJax, that would have a format like:

```
\[\begin{aligned}
2x+3 &= 7 & 2x+3-3 &= 7-3 \\
2x &= 4 & \frac{2x}2 &= \frac42 \\
x &= 2
\end{aligned}\]
```

where `\[...\]` are delimiters indicating that MathJax should process the contents. Aloha editor wraps each line in a `<p>` tag that separates the delimiters so MathJax is unable to process them.

So my question is, is there a way to paste or enter text into aloha without splitting it into multiple text nodes? Alternatively, is there a way to make MathJax read delimiters across tags?

Edit: I'm asking because I don't want to do something like

```
var math="";
_.each($("p:contains(\[)"),function(startEl){
    math= $(startEl).html();
    var startIndex = $(startEl).index();
    var endIndex = $(startEl).parent().find("p:contains(\])").first().index();
    $(startEl).siblings().slice(startIndex, endIndex).each(function(index){
        math+=$(this).html();
    });
    $(startEl).siblings().slice(startIndex, endIndex).remove();
    $(startEl).replaceWith("<p>"+math+"</p>");
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
});
```

to take the TeX inside the separate `<p>`s and put it into one `<p>` because it doesn't feel robust at all

Comment: You might want to check out https://github.com/oerpub/Aloha-Editor which includes plugins for MathJax-based input.

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out; only thing is I'm not sure if I can easily replace the customized aloha editor we're using right now.